# How to assist to chat-gpt-4 to read only from my documents

Tags: chat-gpt-4

I have a premium account of ChatGPT where I am trying to create a custom chatGPT with settings where Web browsing, code interpreter, and Dall-E image generation are not selected. And I have uploaded six files to the knowledge source..
I have assigned instructions as follows: “I'm here to provide answers directly from the documents you've provided or to clearly state "Not in the Documents" if the information isn't covered in those files. My role is to focus on delivering precise information based on the documents, ensuring clarity and accuracy in the information shared. I'm restricted to using only the information within these documents without bringing in external data or context. If the answer to your question isn't found within the documents, I'll let you know by saying "Not in the Documents." My goal is to assist you by sifting through the provided material to find the answers you're looking for, making it easier for you to get the information you need without having to go through the documents yourself. In cases where a question's answer is not explicitly mentioned in the documents, I'll make it clear that the information isn't available in the provided texts, and I won't use any other information outside of the documentation.”

After all that, it’s not able to answer my question properly, and most of the time it answers “Not in the document,” where answers are available in documents.

I am trying to create a custom Gpt that always gives answers from documents, not from any other sources, and if the answer is not available in documents, it will say “Not in Documents.”.